# awarding a bounty

Tags: support, bounty

This is a very simple question, so I'll get started right away. I have a bounty on a question of mine that should probably go to a user who didn't exactly answer all my questions, but contributed a lot of valuable insights. The problem is, this user, instead of starting a new answer, has kept on editing the original post. Now I would like to move the bounty marker to the post or to some of the commentary by this user, and thereafter award the bounty, how do I go about doing this? Thanks! Of course if someone happens to solve it in the remaining time that person will get the bounty. Here is the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283908/amount-of-ways-to-add-m-nodes-to-a-n-length-cycle-without-extra-cycles).

Comment: I find the linked thread a little hard to follow. Have you tried simply requesting the user to post a new answer because you want to award them the bounty?

Comment: I don't even know how to move the bounty marker, currently it is attached to an answer that turned out not to contribute to the main thread.

Comment: Is it me or all the answers except one are by you? If that is the case you should know that you cannot award the bounty to yourself which means that the only answer which is going to be applicable for the bounty is the other answer.

Comment: That is the problem. The answers are not all by me. About 40% is by another user, who does not start his own answers but instead merges his work into the existing structure! This is the user who should receive the bounty as of the present state of affairs.

Comment: You can see this user at work if you look at the edit history of the answers.

Comment: It certainly looks to me like all of your answers have been edited only by you! Are you sure you're talking about [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283908/amount-of-ways-to-add-m-nodes-to-a-n-length-cycle-without-extra-cycles), "Amount of ways to add M nodes to a N length cycle without extra cycles", with four answers by you and one answer by Fardad Jalili? Which one of those answers has the edits by the other user? *Edit:* Are you talking about the edits to the *question* by Guest 86?

Comment: That's right, it refers to the question, my apologies. And if you look at the history you will see that there is a very substantial contribution by Guest 86, including a program, commentary, and additional conjectures.

Comment: The two example computations for small graphs should do the thread a considerable service where readability is concerned, and I wrote them in response to questions by the other user, which he put into the commentary.

Answer (score 3):

[Bounties can only be awarded on answers, and they go to the person who originally posted the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) If you want to award a bounty to someone who has only contributed via comments, question edits, or edits to other people's answers, there is no way to do so directly. I think your best option is to leave a comment requesting the person to consolidate their contributions into a new answer, saying that this will enable you to award them the bounty which would otherwise go to waste.

> I don't even know how to move the bounty marker, currently it is attached to an answer that turned out not to contribute to the main thread.

As Asaf points out in the comments, you cannot award bounties to your own answers. That is why it appears as if the bounty has "attached itself" to the only answer in the post that is not by you. But it's not really attached in any sense. When someone else posts a new answer, you will see options to award the bounty to any one of the answers that are not yours.

Comment: As for the last part, note that only one answer is eligible for a bounty, so it is the only answer on which the bounty awarding button appears.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, @Asaf; I see that I hadn't fully understood your first comment. I've now updated the answer.